# Is it possible to simulate an inner class using functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a React component that does something like this.

```
<Picker>
  <Picker.Item />
</Picker>
```

But using functional components.  Is it possible?

Without functional components I would implement it something like

```
class Picker {
  static Item = () => (<View />)
}
```

But I want to access the `this.state` of the Picker from the `Item` and I can't access that because Item is `static`

I am basically trying to implement something like React-Native Picker which has that style of component.

If it was functional, I can use React Context to pass the necessary data down.  But I liked the `Picker.Item` style.

Comment: inner classes generally cannot access the outer class members, anyway, unless they maintain a parent member of their own. This is equivalent to wanting access to the parent element from within render, something not feasible.

Comment: Having components access each others' state seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: I'm trying to  use the same style like <Picker> from React-Native works.